# Требуется составить запрос используя CriteriaAPI

Tags: sql, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

Имеется три таблицы, между которыми установлена связь. Adverts связана ManyToOne с Users (по User.id) и Profiles связана OneToOne с Users (по User.id). Требуется сделать выборку Объявлений (Adverts) с максимальным рейтингом пользователя (поле - Profiles.userRank). Использую SpringData.
На SQL такой запрос строится легко (выдача правильная):

```
SELECT * FROM adverts a JOIN users s ON a.user_id=s.id JOIN proiles p ON s.id = p.user_id ORDER BY p.user_rank
```

Теперь хочу построить этот запрос, используя Criteria Hibernate и метамодель сущностей.
Делаю так:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Advert> cq = cb.createQuery(Advert.class);
    Root<Advert> root = cq.from(Advert.class);
    //делаем Join с таблицей User по user_id - без ошибок
    root.join(Advert_.user, JoinType.LEFT);
    // пытаюсь сделать join с таблицей Profiles - ОШИБКА в поле Profile_.user (!!!
    root.join(Profile_.user,JoinType.LEFT);
    //что бы потом сделать такой запрос
    CriteriaQuery<Advert> select =
            cq.select(root)
                    .orderBy(
                            cb.desc(root.get(Profile_.userRank) // сортировка по рангу пользователя
                            )
                    );
```

Вопрос: Как правильно сделать join третьей таблицы (Profiles) и получить из нее (userRank)?

Сущности обозначены так:

```
@Table(name = "adverts")
```

public class Advert implements Entity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "adv_topic_id")
private AdvertTopic advertTopic;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "adv_rank_id")
private AdvertRank advertRank;

@Column(name = "adv_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Enumes.AdverType advType;

@Column(name = "adv_text")
private String advText;

@Column(name = "adv_price")
private int advPrice;

@Column(name = "adv_date")
private LocalDate advDate;

@Column(name = "adv_status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Enumes.AdverStatus advStatus;
```

// USERS

```
@Table(name = "users")
```

public class User implements Entity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "role")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Enumes.UserRole role;

// PROFILES
```

@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile implements Entity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "avatar")
private String avatar;

@Column(name = "money_balance")
private int moneyBalance;

@Column(name = "user_rank")
private int userRank;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, добавил поле profiles в таблице user.
Теперь запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
CriteriaQuery<Advert> select =
            cq.select(root)
                    .orderBy(
                            cb.desc(root.get("user").get("profile").get("userRank"))
                            )
                    );
```